# EACCES: permission denied Docker container does not have permissions to write in named volume

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, json-server

There is docker-compose that uses base Dockerfile created image for application.

Dockerfile looks similar to below. Some lines are omitted for reason.

```bash
# common build stage
FROM node:16-alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /server

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# development build stage
FROM build-stage as development-stage

ENV NODE_ENV development

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
# docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build
```

When using this image in docker-compose and adding named volume to service, folder in named volume is not accessible, with message Permission denied. Part of the error below

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/server/api/db.json'

And my docker-compose.yml with a named volume below

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  server:
    build: 
      context: ./server
      target: development-stage
    image: my-app-server-image
    container_name: my-app-server
    volumes:
      - api_server_vol:/server/api
      - ./server:/server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

volumes:
  api_server_vol:
```

When I run the docker-compose without the named volume 'api_server_vol' I can write the file inside the container without any problems. When I add a named volume to save changes, the container does not have permissions to write to the volume's 'db.json' file.

I wonder if there is any solution that indicates that my container application gives read and write access to the named volume, which I believe this was a docker default already.

Comment: I'd expect the default to be that your application is running as root; can you verify this (`docker-compose run server id`) and also check the mounted directory's permissions (`docker-compose run server ls -ld /server/api`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I think is running as root: uid=0(root) and the directory permissions is drwxrwxr-x, something that would need to change?